Monitoring a Configfs file via inotify or epoll
For an userspace application, I would like to monitor a particular ConfigFS without polling it. I know this is possible by using inotify for a regular file and by using epoll for some sysfs files but I am still facing some issues with this particular ConfigFS file.
Does ConfigFS file support monitoring by using inotify or epoll (or any other tools) ?
Thanks a lot in advance for any help

configfs is similar to sysfs. sysfs doesn't support inotify, and I'd expect the same for configfs. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/656717/how-to-attach-a-listener-to-sysfs-files

The basic problem is that reading from these filesystems involves running some code to calculate the current value based on kernel data structures. There's nothing that automatically triggers callbacks when this data changes, so polling is really the only way to do it.
